# Ler variáveis de um objeto que foi criado em outro

Tags: javascript, variáveis, objetos

Estou criando um RPG e encontrei um problema: não consigo criar monstros com níveis.

Meu código está assim:

```js
var xp = 0;

function MonsterCriado(entidade){    
    Lvl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
    //quando um monstro nasce, é gerado um nivel para ele
}

function MonsterMorto(assassino, vitima){    
    xp += Math.floor(Math.random() * (18 - 3) + 3) * vitima.Lvl; 
    //quando eu matar o monstro eu qro ganhar xp baseado no seu nivel
}
```

A questão que não estou conseguindo resolver é: como usar a variável `nivel` do monstro na função `MonsterMorto` para ganhar xp.

Comment: A variável  `Lv1` voce quer dizer?

Comment: Qual o motivo de `(11-1)+1` ?

Comment: Ss, qro usar a variavel lvl

Comment: (11-1)+1 retorna random entre 10 e 1

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando a  variável `Lv1` dentro de `MonsterCriado`, mas na verdade não salva esse valor em lugar nenhum. 
(Bom, na verdade, como não declarou a variável `Lv1` ela é crida no escopo global, o que complica mais ainda a história).

Se quiser que a variável seja um atributo do objeto sendo criado, faça isso com o operador `.` e a variável especial `this`.

Isso aqui foi no prompt interativo do Javascript:

```
function Monstro(){this.level = 2;}

m = new Monstro()
Monstro {level: 2}
m.level

2
```

Comment: Vou tentar, espero q funcione

Comment: Funcionou, vlww